# C++ mistakes with linking virtual function

Tags: c++

I got a weird problem with C++. Well, I tried to write an a simple program on seven separated files. Everything was going well, until an error occurred which caused that I can't go any further. Can someone tell what have I done wrong ?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "item.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int x;
Magazine some_magazine;
Book some_book;

Item *wsk_instr;

cout << "Witamy w ksiegarni" << endl << endl;
cout << "Wcisnij 1 aby kupic ksiazke" << endl;
cout << "Wcisnij 2 aby sprzedac ksiazke" << endl;
cout << "Wcisnij 3 aby zobaczyc jakie ksiazki mamy" << endl;
cin >> x;

switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        cout << "Kup ksiazke" <<endl;
        wsk_instr = &some_magazine;
        wsk_instr -> show();
        cout << "Ktora ksiazke chcesz kupic?" << endl;
        cout << "Ksiazka pierwsza - 1, ksiazka druga - 2, ksiazka trzecia - 3" << endl;
        wsk_instr = &some_book;
        wsk_instr -> sell();
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Sprzedaj ksiazke" << endl;
        cout << "Jaka ksiazke chcesz sprzedać? Podaj tytul:\t";
        wsk_instr = &some_book;
        wsk_instr -> buy();
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << "Pokaz co mamy na stanie" << endl;
        wsk_instr = &some_magazine;
        wsk_instr -> show();
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Nie wybrales nic" << endl;
        break;
}
}
```

item.cpp & item.hpp

```
item.cpp
#include <iostream>

void buy() {};
void sell() {};
void show() {};

item.hpp
#ifndef item_hpp
#define item_hpp

class Item {
public:
void virtual buy();
void virtual sell();
void virtual show();
};
#endif /* item_h */
```

magazine.cpp & magazine.hpp

```
magazine.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "magazine.hpp"
#include "book.hpp"

//dodawanie elementu na koniec wektora
void Magazine::add() {
std::cout << "Jaka ksiazke chcesz sprzedać? Podaj tytul:\t";
std::string book_title;
std::cin >> book_title;
table_of_books.push_back(book_title);
}

//usuwanie ostatniego elementu wektora
void Magazine::remove() {
std::cout << "Ktora ksiazke chcesz kupic? Podaj numer:\t";
int choose;
std::cin >> choose;
table_of_books.erase(table_of_books.begin() + choose);
}

//pokazywanie wielkosci wektora (ilosci elementow w nim)
void Magazine::show() {
std::cout << "W magazynie jest: " << table_of_books.size() << " ksiazek. A oto one:" << std::endl;
//wyswietlanie wszystkich ksiazek jakie sa w wektorze
for(int counter = 0; counter < table_of_books.size(); counter ++) {
    std::cout << table_of_books[counter] << std::endl;
    }    
}


magazine.hpp
#ifndef magazine_hpp
#define magazine_hpp
#include <vector>
#include "item.hpp"
#include "book.hpp"

class Magazine : public Item {
std::vector <std::string> table_of_books { "Potop", "Zemsta", "Dziady", };

public:
void add();
void remove();
void show();
};
#endif /* magazine_hpp */
```

book.cpp & book.hpp

```
book.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "book.hpp"
#include "magazine.hpp"

void Book::buy() {
add_book_to_the_magazine.add();
}

void Book::sell() {
delete_book_from_the_magazine.remove();
}

book.hpp
#ifndef book_hpp
#define book_hpp
#include "item.hpp"
#include "magazine.hpp"

class Book : public Item {

Magazine add_book_to_the_magazine;
Magazine delete_book_from_the_magazine;

void buy();
void sell();
};

#endif /* book_hpp */
```

My problem is with these two lines:

main.cpp

```
Magazine some_magazine;
Book some_book;
```

Xcode says that: unknown type name 'Magazine' and 'Book'. Sounds like there is a problem with linking? But class magazine and class book are set to public for class item. So, what's the problem?

Comment: That's not a problem with linking. That's a problem with you not including the header files.

Comment: That's normal, in main.cpp you aren't including book.hpp and magazine.hpp, where Magazine and Book are declared.

Comment: this answer was simple, but for future posts, please post a [mcve] (with emphasis on the **minimal** part)

Comment: Too much text is written just for few missing includes.

Comment: Whoa! 
Thank's for so fast answers. I feel ashamed for such stupid mistake.... but however now I got warning message in book.hpp that says exactly the same

     Magazine add_book_to_the_magazine;
     Magazine delete_book_from_the_magazine;

Also excuse for such an a long text, I promise to do it better next time!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the book.hpp and magazine.hpp at the top of main.cpp:

```
#include "magazine.hpp"
#include "book.hpp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main.cpp does not include magazine.hpp and book.hpp.